Playing MP3 file on Adafruit vs1053 breakout board produces no sound
I am using an Arduino Uno 3 wired to an Adafruit VS1053 CODEC breakout board with an SD Card attached. On the SD Card is the file "track001.mp3" which is roughly 3 seconds long. I am trying to run the example from https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_VS1053_Library/blob/master/examples/player_interrupts/player_interrupts.ino
I can hear the sine test being played but when I try to play the MP3 file using either the playFullFile or startPlayingFile functions there is no sound. The program seems to pause for roughly 3 seconds, making it seem that the file is being played but no sound is produced. I have made print statements in the SD.cpp library file and can see that the buffer data is being fed and I can see from the terminal when I print the contents of the directory on the SD Card that the file is 52kB bytes which is exactly what it should be.
What may be reasons the functions do not produce any sound?
Edit:
I have tried unmodified MP3 files, MP3 files where I have removed the ID3 headers, WAV files and OGG files all with the same result

"the file "track001.mp3"" may be compressed/encoded in a way that's not supported. Inspect its details, since MP3s can vary alot. Also try other files and other formats (f.e. .ogg).
